# Why does this code tell me the type or namespace could not be found?

Tags: c#, reflection

Given the following code:

```
var property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Id");
var temp = (property.PropertyType)id;
```

VS underlines 'property' in the second line and tells me the type or namespace cannot be found. Why? I've tried with and without `using System.Reflection` at the top and get the same result.

I was able to work around it by using `Convert.ChangeType(id, property.PropertyType)`, but I'm curious what about the C# spec makes the previous code invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expects a type (not variable of type `System.Type` but actual type) between the parentheses, but such type (`property.PropertyType`) doesn't exist.
To prove this add this to your code:

```
public class property
{
    public class PropertyType
    {

    }
}
```

Now, the compiler will be satisfied but this is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to *cast* via something which is only known at execution time. C# doesn't work like that. The type part of a cast isn't "an expression which evaluates to a `Type` reference" - it's *the name of a type or type parameter*.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, but you're not going to be able to do it via casting like that. What do you expect the compile-time type of `temp` to be? Are you aware that `var` is just compile-time type inference, not dynamic typing?

If you can give us more information about what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: You're right, I had a brain fart. Can't cast at design time to something that is only known at runtime. Doh!